# Can I pull a git work-tree?

Tags: git

I have a repository **A**, and a clone of it, named **B**. Then, I have edited a file in the **A** and not commit it. My question is if I can run `git pull` in **B** to get the edition in the **A**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pull revisions, i.e. commits. If an edit isn't committed, it isn't in the repository and can't be pulled. However, you could do something like

1. Commit the edits in repository **A**
2. Pull them to repository **B**
3. In repository **A**, `git reset --hard HEAD^` to undo the latest commit and erase the edit.

If you want to keep the edit in repository **A** but not the commit, omit the `--hard` option to `reset`.

Answer (score 3):

If no "commit and push" was performed, how can a client `pull` get access to new revisions?

Short answer: no.

Comment: You don't need a push to perform a pull on B. But that doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to commit the file to the master branch, commit it to another branch and pull that.